# Relative Import Errors Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, relative-path

the tree of the project is

```
C:.
├───.pytest_cache
│   └───v
│       └───cache
├───alembic
├───app
│   ├───models
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───routers
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───tests
│   └───__pycache__
├───venv
│   ├───Include
│   │   └───site
│   │       └───python3.9
│   │           └───greenlet
│   ├───Lib
│   │   └───site-packages
│   │       ├───alembic
│   │       │   ├───autogenerate
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───ddl
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───operations
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───runtime
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───script
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───templates
│   │       │   │   ├───async
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───generic
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───multidb
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───pylons
│   │       │   │       └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───testing
│   │       │   │   ├───plugin
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───suite
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───util
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───alembic-1.7.5.dist-info
│   │       ├───anyio
│   │       │   ├───abc
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───streams
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_backends
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_core
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───anyio-3.4.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───asgiref
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───asgiref-3.4.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───atomicwrites
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───atomicwrites-1.4.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───attr
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───attrs-21.2.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───autopep8-1.6.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───bcrypt
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───bcrypt-3.2.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───bson
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───certifi
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───certifi-2021.10.8.dist-info
│   │       ├───cffi
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───cffi-1.15.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───charset_normalizer
│   │       │   ├───assets
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───cli
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───charset_normalizer-2.0.8.dist-info
│   │       ├───click
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───click-8.0.3.dist-info
│   │       ├───colorama
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───colorama-0.4.4.dist-info
│   │       ├───cryptography
│   │       │   ├───hazmat
│   │       │   │   ├───backends
│   │       │   │   │   ├───openssl
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───bindings
│   │       │   │   │   ├───openssl
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───_rust
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───primitives
│   │       │   │   │   ├───asymmetric
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───ciphers
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───kdf
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───serialization
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───twofactor
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───x509
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───cryptography-36.0.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───dns
│   │       │   ├───rdtypes
│   │       │   │   ├───ANY
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───CH
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───IN
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───dnspython-2.1.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───dotenv
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───ecdsa
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───ecdsa-0.17.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───email_validator
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───email_validator-1.1.3.dist-info
│   │       ├───fastapi
│   │       │   ├───dependencies
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───middleware
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───openapi
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───security
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───fastapi-0.70.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───greenlet
│   │       │   ├───platform
│   │       │   ├───tests
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───greenlet-1.1.2.dist-info
│   │       ├───gridfs
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───h11
│   │       │   ├───tests
│   │       │   │   ├───data
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───h11-0.12.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───httptools
│   │       │   ├───parser
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───httptools-0.2.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───idna
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───idna-3.3.dist-info
│   │       ├───iniconfig
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───iniconfig-1.1.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───itsdangerous
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───itsdangerous-2.0.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───jinja2
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───Jinja2-3.0.3.dist-info
│   │       ├───jose
│   │       │   ├───backends
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───mako
│   │       │   ├───ext
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───Mako-1.1.6.dist-info
│   │       ├───markupsafe
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───MarkupSafe-2.0.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───mongoengine
│   │       │   ├───base
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───queryset
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───mongoengine-0.23.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───multipart
│   │       │   ├───tests
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───orjson
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───orjson-3.6.4.dist-info
│   │       ├───packaging
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───packaging-21.3.dist-info
│   │       ├───passlib
│   │       │   ├───crypto
│   │       │   │   ├───scrypt
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───_blowfish
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───ext
│   │       │   │   ├───django
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───handlers
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───tests
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───utils
│   │       │   │   ├───compat
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_data
│   │       │   │   └───wordsets
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───passlib-1.7.4.dist-info
│   │       ├───pip
│   │       │   ├───_internal
│   │       │   │   ├───cli
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───commands
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───distributions
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───index
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───locations
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───metadata
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───models
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───network
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───operations
│   │       │   │   │   ├───build
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───install
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───req
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───resolution
│   │       │   │   │   ├───legacy
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───resolvelib
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───utils
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───vcs
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_vendor
│   │       │   │   ├───cachecontrol
│   │       │   │   │   ├───caches
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───certifi
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───chardet
│   │       │   │   │   ├───cli
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───metadata
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───colorama
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───distlib
│   │       │   │   │   ├───_backport
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───html5lib
│   │       │   │   │   ├───filters
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───treeadapters
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───treebuilders
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───treewalkers
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───_trie
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───idna
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───msgpack
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───packaging
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───pep517
│   │       │   │   │   ├───in_process
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───pkg_resources
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───platformdirs
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───progress
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───requests
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───resolvelib
│   │       │   │   │   ├───compat
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───tenacity
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───tomli
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───urllib3
│   │       │   │   │   ├───contrib
│   │       │   │   │   │   ├───_securetransport
│   │       │   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───packages
│   │       │   │   │   │   ├───backports
│   │       │   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   │   ├───ssl_match_hostname
│   │       │   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   ├───util
│   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───webencodings
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pip-21.3.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───pkg_resources
│   │       │   ├───extern
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───tests
│   │       │   │   └───data
│   │       │   │       └───my-test-package-source
│   │       │   │           └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_vendor
│   │       │   │   ├───packaging
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pluggy
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pluggy-1.0.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───psycopg2
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───psycopg2-2.9.2.dist-info
│   │       ├───py
│   │       │   ├───_code
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_io
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_log
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_path
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_process
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_vendored_packages
│   │       │   │   ├───apipkg
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───apipkg-2.0.0.dist-info
│   │       │   │   ├───iniconfig
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───iniconfig-1.1.1.dist-info
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───py-1.11.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───pyasn1
│   │       │   ├───codec
│   │       │   │   ├───ber
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───cer
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───der
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───native
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───compat
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───type
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pyasn1-0.4.8.dist-info
│   │       ├───pycodestyle-2.8.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───pycparser
│   │       │   ├───ply
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pycparser-2.21.dist-info
│   │       ├───pydantic
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pydantic-1.8.2.dist-info
│   │       ├───pymongo
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pymongo-3.12.3.dist-info
│   │       ├───pyparsing
│   │       │   ├───diagram
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pyparsing-3.0.6.dist-info
│   │       ├───pytest
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───pytest-6.2.5.dist-info
│   │       ├───python_dotenv-0.19.2.dist-info
│   │       ├───python_jose-3.3.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───python_multipart-0.0.5-py3.9.egg-info
│   │       ├───PyYAML-5.4.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───requests
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───requests-2.26.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───rsa
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───rsa-4.8.dist-info
│   │       ├───setuptools
│   │       │   ├───command
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───extern
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_distutils
│   │       │   │   ├───command
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_vendor
│   │       │   │   ├───more_itertools
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───packaging
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───setuptools-57.4.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───six-1.16.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───sniffio
│   │       │   ├───_tests
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───sniffio-1.2.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───sqlalchemy
│   │       │   ├───connectors
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───databases
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───dialects
│   │       │   │   ├───firebird
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───mssql
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───mysql
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───oracle
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───postgresql
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───sqlite
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───sybase
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───engine
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───event
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───ext
│   │       │   │   ├───asyncio
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───declarative
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───mypy
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───future
│   │       │   │   ├───orm
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───orm
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───pool
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───sql
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───testing
│   │       │   │   ├───plugin
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───suite
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───util
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───SQLAlchemy-1.4.27.dist-info
│   │       ├───starlette
│   │       │   ├───middleware
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───starlette-0.16.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───toml
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───toml-0.10.2.dist-info
│   │       ├───typing_extensions-4.0.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───ujson-4.3.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───urllib3
│   │       │   ├───contrib
│   │       │   │   ├───_securetransport
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───packages
│   │       │   │   ├───backports
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───ssl_match_hostname
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───util
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───urllib3-1.26.7.dist-info
│   │       ├───uvicorn
│   │       │   ├───lifespan
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───loops
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───middleware
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───protocols
│   │       │   │   ├───http
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   ├───websockets
│   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───supervisors
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_handlers
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───uvicorn-0.15.0.dist-info
│   │       ├───watchgod
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───watchgod-0.7.dist-info
│   │       ├───websockets
│   │       │   ├───extensions
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───legacy
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───websockets-10.1.dist-info
│   │       ├───yaml
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───_distutils_hack
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───_pytest
│   │       │   ├───assertion
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───config
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───mark
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_code
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   ├───_io
│   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       ├───_yaml
│   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │       └───__pycache__
│   └───Scripts
└───__pycache__
```

All over the project right now I have import errors,one file example is inside the tests folder I have the conftest file,which in the start has the imports :

```
from app import schemas
from app import main
from app.oauth2 import create_access_token
from app.database import connect
from app.models.models_post import Post
```

and gives me the error :

```
ImportError while loading conftest 'C:\Users\invis\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\jc_api\tests\conftest.py'.
conftest.py:6: in <module>
    from app import main
..\app\main.py:3: in <module>
    from app.routers import post, user, auth, vote
..\app\routers\post.py:3: in <module>
    from .. import schemas, oauth2
..\app\oauth2.py:7: in <module>
    from ..app.models.models_user import User
E   ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

when I try to use .. before app in the imports ,the error changes to

```
ImportError while loading conftest 'C:\Users\invis\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\jc_api\tests\conftest.py'.
conftest.py:5: in <module>
    from ..app import schemas
E   ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I searched all over stack overflow and the internet and don't know what to do,if anyone could say at least a thought or anything like that I would appreciate A LOT,thanks for the attenttion and reading still here :)

Comment: I assume you are calling conftest.py from within the tests folder. Try adding `import sys` and `sys.path.append("..")` at the very top of your conftest.py file (before your `app` imports). However, you might run into other package-import problems, as i think, the whole module was probably called from a folder above.

Comment: Try to put the ```Tests``` folder into the ```App``` folder.